# Conditional hyperlinkfield in a gridview? ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I put a hyperlinkfield into a gridview, but I realise sometimes I want it to be clickable and sometimes not, depending on the data.

If the item is A or B, I want a hyperlink to bibble.aspx?id=123 , otherwise I just want plain text.

What's the best way? Should I be using another type of field for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better off with a template field and a hyperlink control, with the NavigateUrl determined by a ternary operator.

Answer (score 3):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
     onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column to check">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCrtl" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column Name">

        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>



protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // you may need to do this if you didnt use templatefield;
        // string val = e.Row.Cells[<column index>].Text;
        // if its templatefield do following;
        Label lbl = e.Row.FindControl("lblCrtl") as Label; 

        Button btn = null;

        if (lbl.Text == "Car") // put your own value to check, my case it was Car
        {
            btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = "Test";
            e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(btn); // cells<column index that control will be added>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar to this, with a templatefield, but for some reason e.Row.Cells[7].Text is "" which can't be right...

Comment: if you used templatefield you cant access the control like e.Row.Cells[7].Text, you rather use e.Row.FindControls("ctrlID"); and use its properties depending what control you used.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is I want either a label, or a hyperlink. So should I put the label into the templatefield, then in the codebehind, remove it and add a hyperlink? Also wouldn't giving it an ID cause more than one label with the same ID on the page?

Comment: where is the control which helps you to decide if its label or hyperlink?

Comment: It's actually the data that comes back in that field. It's a status for something, and if the status is set to "None", it should be a hyperlink, otherwise it will just be plain text.

Comment: ((System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord) e.Row.DataItem)["Status"]=="None"

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the RowDataBound event of your GridView.

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) demonstrates how to use the RowDataBound event to modify the value of a field in the data source before it is displayed in a GridView control.

Comment: Yeah I have just done this and am about to add a hyperlink... the only problem now I just hit is how to get the ID to append to the hyperlink url. It's not displayed as a field (although it makes up part of the hyperlink in another field), although it is pulled back into the datasource. How can I extract it in code? Usually I would just use the datakeyname property. It might be obvious, I am still new to gridviews;D

Comment: I was off to lunch - looks like you got your solution in the meanwhile :)